# Border around Pie Chart in MPChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there a way to add a stroke to the Paint for a piechart? I want strokes on all my slices, not only outside but inside as well. I'm not seeing any method for this in the library. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there is an API in library for this. So I ended up modifying the library. 
I created a paint object with Style.STROKE for each slice of PieChart and painted it over each slice path. So, in class **PieChartRenderer.drawDataSet()** just after:

```
mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(mPathBuffer, mRenderPaint);
```

I added following lines of code:

```
Paint strokePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
strokePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
strokePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(mPathBuffer, strokePaint);
```

You can also make strokePaint a member variable of PieChartRenderer for efficiency.

Also, if you don't want double lines between each slice just set dataSet.setSliceSpace(0f);

Of course you can also extend PieChart and PieChartRenderer and use CustomPieChart for creating a pie chart so that you don't have to modify the library.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you can do it by adding radius to pie chart and add color into it.

```
chart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
chart.setHoleRadius(60);
chart.setHoleColor(0xFFffffff);
```

Comment: I want stroke around each slice not just at center. Thanks though!!